# python regex replace all occurances with the matched string

Tags: python, regex

I have a document i'm trying to display it in a jinja template. I am trying to replace the string like this `negxxx string xxxneg` needs to become `<span class="SomeCssClass_neg_xxx"> string </span>`. the problem is with the matched group numbering `\1` that i am using. I know i have multiple matches not only 1. need some help.

```
import re
StringIn = 'negxxx data1 xxxneg  out of span negxxx data2 xxxneg negzzz data1 zzzneg  out of span negzzz data2 zzzneg'
StringIn = re.sub(r"negxxx(.*)xxxneg", r"<span class='neg_xxx'>\1</span>" , StringIn)
StringIn = re.sub(r"negzzz(.*)zzzneg", r"<span class='neg_zzz'>\1</span>" , StringIn)
print StringIn
```

I get:

```
<span class='neg_xxx'> data1 xxxneg  out of span negxxx data2 </span> <span class='neg_zzz'> data1 zzzneg  out of span negzzz data2 </span>
```

which is not correct, what i need is:

```
<span class='neg_xxx'> data1 </span>   out of span <span class='neg_xxx'> data2 </span><span class='neg_zzz'> data1 </span>  out of span <span class='neg_zzz'> data2 </span>
```

Comment: For a second I read it as **ninja** template. ☻

Comment: Let me do a wild guess. Try with lazy `?` quantifier. `.*` is matching too much. Use `.*?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `.*` is racing to the end of the string and only backing up to nearest (to end of string) "xxxneg".  Use a lazy quantifier, `.*?`, which will eat one character at a time only and then try to match the rest of the pattern:

```
import re
StringIn = 'negxxx data1 xxxneg  out of span negxxx data2 xxxneg negzzz data1 zzzneg  out of span negzzz data2 zzzneg'
StringIn = re.sub(r"negxxx(.*?)xxxneg", r"<span class='neg_xxx'>\1</span>" , StringIn)
StringIn = re.sub(r"negzzz(.*?)zzzneg", r"<span class='neg_zzz'>\1</span>" , StringIn)
print StringIn
```

Comment: negxxx some data with a new line \n xxxneg, did not work. Any suggestions ?